# For every ring R, every left R-module M can be imbedded as a submodule of an injective left R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

Prove that for every ring $R$, every left $R$-module $M$ can be imbedded as a submodule of an injective left $R$-module

Comment: page 197 of [Hungerford](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=hungerford+algebra+Every+unitary+module+A+over+a+ring+R+with+identity+may+he+++embedded+in+an+injective+K-module.&source=bl&ots=cSN7kvU6Wh&sig=o_DgA2AiXjqbcvuJIuN-EeVrk0w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipsbKclJvMAhWB1iwKHTgsB-UQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard dualization trick : for any $R$-module $A$, write $A^* = Hom_\mathbb{Z}(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, which is a $R$-module. This gives a contravariant functor from the category of $R$-modules to itself.

Then write $A^*$ as quotient of a free module : $\bigoplus_{i\in I} R \to A^*\to 0$. Dualizing : $0\to A^{**}\to \prod_{i\in I} R^*$ (this is exact because $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module, since it's divisible).

Now $R^*$ is injective (because $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(R,\bullet)$ has a left adjoint and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective, so it's sent to an injective object), so $\prod_{i\in I} R^*$ is injective.

We conclude by the fact that the canonical $A\to A^{**}$ given by $a\mapsto ev_a$ (the evaluation map at $a$) is injective, so $A\to A^{**}\to \prod_{i\in I} R^*$ is an injective morphism to an injective $R$-module.